# Proof of the existence of a mirror Calabi–Yau manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, kahler-manifolds, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau

Let $X$ be a Calabi–Yau threefold. Here, Calabi–Yau is understood to a mean a smooth simply connected projective threefold with $h^1(\mathcal{O}_X) = h^2(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ and holomorphically trivial canonical bundle $K_X \simeq \mathcal{O}_X$. The only variable Hodge numbers for such a manifold are $h^{1,1}$ and $h^{1,2}$, where $h^{1,1}$ is the Picard number of $X$, and $h^{1,2}$ is the dimension of the versal deformation space of $X$. In particular, if $h^{1,2}=0$, the Calabi–Yau manifold is said to be rigid.

To my understanding, mirror symmetry predicts that Calabi–Yau threefolds with $h^{1,2}>0$ come in pairs. That is, for a Calabi–Yau threefold with Hodge numbers $h^{1,1}(X)$ and $h^{1,2}(X)$, there is another Calabi–Yau threefold $\check{X}$ with $h^{1,1}(\check{X}) = h^{1,2}(X)$ and $h^{1,2}(\check{X}) = h^{1,1}(X)$. Since $b_2(X) = h^{1,1}(X)$ must be positive, the existence of a mirror (in this sense, that is a projective Calabi–Yau threefold), mandates that $h^{1,2}(X)>0$. I'm aware that more general notions have been introduced, but that is a story for another day. The evidence for the existence of mirror Calabi–Yau manifolds comes from mapping out the Hodge numbers of Calabi–Yau threefolds which arise as complete intersections, hence, the evidence is empirical.

> Question: Are there any results that directly prove the existence of a mirror Calabi–Yau, for certain classes of Calabi–Yau manifolds? More precisely, suppose I have a Calabi–Yau manifold with a given Hodge pair $(h^{1,1}, h^{1,2}) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Are there any Hodge pairs for which I can assert the existence of a mirror?

For instance, using conifold transitions, I can probably take a Calabi–Yau threefold that I can hold in my hand, and construct a mirror if I know enough about the rational curves in the manifold. I'm more concerned with the construction/existence of the mirror in the cases where we can't hold the Calabi–Yau manifold in our hands, we really only have the Hodge numbers at our disposal.

Comment: Have you seen Batyrev's result? https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9310003

Comment: @CraniumClamp I had not seen this result. Although I'm primarily interested in non-toric varieties, this is still very interesting. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!